# How can I make RVM to use a local tarball?

Tags: rvm

My Inet connection is slow. I have downloaded Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.1 and 1.9.2 on a 32bits machine (with RVM). Now I want to install those same ruby interpreters on my 64bits, but I don't want to download them again. Can I instruct rvm to use a local tarball?

Comment: You don't want to use a 32bit version of Ruby on a 64bit machine. The native code associated with a lot of gems, and compiled as they're installed, will get mad. Using RVM you can export your gemset, then reimport it on the 64bit host, and the gems will recompile, but with the 32bit interpreter I suspect your results will be sub-optimal. Copy the source archives over, stick them in `~/.rvm/archives` and RVM should see them when you do `install`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's possible to *instruct* RVM to use a local tarball, but it will use any files present in $rvm_path/archives (e.g. /home/me/.rvm/archives/) instead of downloading them again from the internet.

You should be able to copy these files from one machine to another.